# Is conditional probability always meaningful

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Problem:

A bag contains $4$ red and $5$ white balls. Balls are drawn from the bag without replacement.

Let $A$ be the event that first ball drawn is white and let $B$ denote the event that the second ball drawn is red. Find

(i) $P(B\mid A)$

(ii) $P(A\mid B)$

My confusion is that should $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$

Can we say that in general if $P(A\mid B)$ exists then $P(B\mid A)$ should also exist?

Comment: Certainly both of these conditional probabilities exist, and the events $A$ and $B$ are _not_ independent (as they would be if $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If the ball drawn is placed back into the bag, then A and B would be independent and P(A|B) = P(A). In your case it's not true.

Comment: If you think about your "probability space" as being all possible ways balls can be drawn out of the bag, then it makes sense because you then are asking questions about all possible sequences of ball drawings.

Answer (score 3):

Let the event space be

$$\Omega=\{(r,r),(r,w),(w,r),(w,w)\}$$
the corresponding probabilities are
$$\frac{12}{72},\frac{20}{72},\frac{20}{72},\frac{20}{72}.$$

Then

$$Pr(A\cap B)=Pr((w,r))=\frac{20}{72}$$

and

$$Pr(B)=Pr(\{(r,r),(w,r)\})=\frac{12}{72}+\frac{20}{72}=\frac{32}{72}$$

and

$$Pr(A)=Pr(\{(w,r),(w,w)\})=\frac{40}{72}$$

so,

$$Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}=\frac{\frac{20}{72}}{\frac{32}{72}}=\frac58.$$

and

$$Pr(B\mid A)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(A)}=\frac{\frac{20}{72}}{\frac{40}{72}}=\frac12.$$

---

In general we cannot say that if $Pr(A\mid B)$ exists then $Pr(B\mid A)$ also exists. Let simply $Pr(A)=0<Pr(B)$. Then $Pr(A\mid B)=0$ but $Pr(B\mid A)$ is not defined.

Comment: Because we are sampling without replacement, the denominator in the probabilities should be $9\times 8$, not $9\times 9$.

Comment: Thx @ByronSchmuland. It was just a "continuous" typo.

Answer (score 2):

In general:

$$P(B|A)P(A)=P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)$$

If you can find $P(A),P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$ then this enables you to find $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$.

Note that $P(A|B)=P(A)$ leads to $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ i.e. independence of $A$ and $B$.

In your question $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

---

Hints:

- To find $P(B)$ realize that the $9$ balls all have *equal* probability to become the second ball drawn, and $4$ of them are red, so...
- Actually finding $P(B|A)$ "directly" is somehow easyer than finding $P(A\cap B)$. If the first ball has been drawn and is white then there are $8$ balls left and $4$ of them are red, so...

Answer (score 2):

$P(A \mid B) \neq P(A)$.

$$P(A \mid B)= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{\frac5{18}}{\frac59\times\frac48+\frac49\times\frac38} = \frac{5}{8}$$

We have $P(A)=\frac{5}{9}$. The intuition behind this is that $B$ makes it more likely that a white ball has been drawn the first time, because then $B$ is more likely.

The key in the problem is that the balls are drawn without replacement. Otherwise we would have $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$.

---

Conditional probability is always meaningful. $P(A \mid B)=P(A)$ also give information. It namely tells you that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we say that in general if $P(A\mid B)$ exists then $P(B\mid A)$
>   should also exist?

Not necessarily. I modifiy your exercise.

> A bag contains $4$ red and $5$ white balls. Balls are drawn from the
>   bag without replacement.
>
> Let $A$ be the event that first ball drawn is white and let $B$ denote the event that the second ball drawn is **black**. Find
>
> (i) $P(B \mid A)$
>
> (ii) $P(A\mid B)$

$P(B)=0$, therefore $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ is not defined.